# JBossCache evict() versus removeNode()

Tags: caching, jboss-cache

Reading [JBossCache documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosscache/3.2.1.GA/userguide_en/html_single/index.html#d0e3242),  there are different policies for eviction

> JBoss Cache also ships with RemoveOnEvictActionPolicy, which calls **Cache.removeNode()** for each node that needs to be evicted, instead of **Cache.evict()**.

I've checked the documentation and API but can't figure out the difference between the two.

Does anyone know such a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the RemoveNodeCommand() and EvictCommand()...

removeNode() removes the node and the nodes children if it has any.

evict() removes the data from a node but does not remove children. Only if the node is a leaf does it remove the node as well.

(version 3.1.0.GA)